# How to calculate the grey-level co-occurrence matrix with only some pixels?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to calculate the `skimage.feature.texture.greycomatrix()`. Now, I have tried it with the following parameters:

```py
skimage.feature.texture.greycomatrix(image, [1], [0], levels=256, symmetric=False, normed=False)
```

But, what I want to do, is to calculate this matrix with only some pixels.

I have this mask:

[image]

And, I have this image:

[image]

And, I only want to calculate the intersection pixels between the white mask and the picture. I don't want to calculate the mask with black pixels or other elements left over, only with the pixels of the image that intersect with the white area of the mask like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Solely using [skimage.measure.greycomatrix](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#greycomatrix), I don't think you'll be able to achieve that, since there's no `mask` parameter or similar. So, I guess, you'd need to build something on your own here.

My idea would be to set all unwanted pixels to `-1`, get the desired correspondences with respect to the `(x, y)` offset, filter out all those containing at least one `-1` entry, and count the occurences of all remaining correspondences. Such, you neglect all correspondences which contain a pixel outside the mask.

To show that for a simple example (cf. the [first example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#greycomatrix) from `skimage.measure.greycomatrix`):

```py
import numpy as np

# https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#greycomatrix
image = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 1],
                  [0, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 2, 3, 3]], dtype=np.uint8)
h, w = image.shape

# Set offset and levels (assuming range [0 ... max] here)
x_off, y_off = (1, 0)
levels = np.max(image) + 1

# Temporary matrix
temp = -np.ones((h+y_off, w+x_off), int)
temp[:h, :w] = image
temp = temp[y_off:, x_off:]

# Get correspondences
temp = np.vstack([image.flatten(), temp.flatten()]).T

# Filter correspondences with at least one entry -1, and count correspondences
temp = temp[~np.any(temp == -1, axis=1), :]
temp = np.unique(temp, axis=0, return_counts=True)

# Create GLCM
glcm = np.zeros((levels, levels), int)
glcm[temp[0][:, 0], temp[0][:, 1]] = temp[1]
print(glcm)
# [[2 2 1 0]
#  [0 2 0 0]
#  [0 0 3 1]
#  [0 0 0 1]]
```

That's in line with the results of `skimage.measure.greycomatrix`.

For your actual image and mask, that'd be the full code (sorry for using OpenCV here; for me, it's somehow faster to prototype):

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Read image and mask
image = cv2.imread('us.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)[:857, :1211]
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)[:857, :1211]

# Get bounding rectangle, crop image and mask
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(mask)
image = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
mask = mask[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# DEBUG: Count non-zero pixels of mask
print('# non-zero pixels mask:', cv2.countNonZero(mask))

# Set all non-masked pixels in image to -1
image = image.astype(int)
image[~mask.astype(bool)] = -1
h, w = image.shape

# Set offset and levels (assuming range [0 ... max] here)
x_off, y_off = (1, 0)
levels = np.max(image) + 1

# Temporary matrix
temp = -np.ones((h+y_off, w+x_off), int)
temp[:h, :w] = image
temp = temp[y_off:, x_off:]

# Get correspondences
temp = np.vstack([image.flatten(), temp.flatten()]).T

# Filter correspondences with at least one entry -1, and count correspondences
temp = temp[~np.any(temp == -1, axis=1), :]
temp = np.unique(temp, axis=0, return_counts=True)

# Create GLCM
glcm = np.zeros((levels, levels), int)
glcm[temp[0][:, 0], temp[0][:, 1]] = temp[1]

# DEBUG: Count number of correspondences found in GLCM
print('# correspondences found in GLCM:', np.sum(glcm))

# Some visualization
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 8))
plt.imshow(glcm, cmap='hot'), plt.colorbar()
plt.tight_layout(), plt.show()
```

The GLCM would be too large to `print`, so the plot:

[image: GLCM]

Let's see the additional `DEBUG` output:

```
# non-zero pixels mask: 18636
# correspondences found in GLCM: 18259
```

There are 18,636 non-zero pixels in your mask, but only 18,259 correspondences were counted in the GLCM. I haven't counted those pixels to be neglected, but for offset `(1, 0)`, the difference of about `400` seems reasonable.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Matplotlib:    3.4.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! this is amazing!! So with that, I'm going to obtain the matrix with the texture of the part that is covered with the white mask, right? Is it ok if for reading the image I use: image = np.array(image)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)[:857, :1211]

Comment: And for reading the mask I use: mask = mask[:857, :1211] ?   It's the only way I don't get errors

Comment: Last question, with this matrix I'm trying to use skimage.feature.texture.greycoprops(glcm, prop='contrast') but I have this error: ValueError: The parameter `P` must be a 4-dimensional array because glcm for me it's 174 x 174. How can that be possible?

Comment: (174, 174) sorry. My previous P was: (256, 256, 1, 1)

Comment: thanks a lot!! I can modify the question if you need more info.

Comment: Read in your image as you've done before. Right now, in my implementation, `image` is assumed to be a single-channel (grayscale) NumPy array of type `np.uint8`. You haven't shown any code to work with, so now it's your part to possibly adapt presented code to your existing solution. | You can't simply feed the resulting `glcm` to `skimage.feature.greycoprops`, because I don't save the distance `d` or the angle `theta`. You'd need to add that yourself, if you want to have that, too. Caveat: I never stated to provide a "masked substitute" for `skimage.feature.greycomatrix` ...

Comment: ... here, but "only" a custom way to calculate the GLCM with the stated requirements.

Comment: hello, sorry that it's been a lomg time since this answer. But I wanted to ask you what do you mean with correspondences and why do we need them. Thank you!

Comment: I simply used the term "correspondences" instead of "co-occurring grayscale values". And, those are the two pixels defined by the offset which are used for the single comparisons to obtain the [co-occurrence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_matrix).

Comment: hello again! please can you explain me why the unwanted values are set at -1? that means that we are going to ignore them automatically? or you have defined somewhere to ignore them? thanks again!!!

Comment: Here, `temp = temp[~np.any(temp == -1, axis=1), :]`, all correspondences with at least one `-1` entry are omitted. So, the values are explicitly set to `-1`, yes. You could use any value outside of your limits to filter out the unwanted values.